# Динамическое управление содержимым виджетов в айтеме ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

Задача: листвью из картинки, текста и чекбокса. Данные из БД.
Если чекбокс включен, картинка меняется на другую.
+ сохранение, удаление и редактирование записей.

На данный момент имею вот что.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;

public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView tvName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    tvName.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    checkBox.setChecked((cursor.getInt(2) == 0 ? false:true));
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
    } else imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_avatar);
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) convertView = layoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                checkBox.isChecked() = true;
            }
            else checkBox.isChecked() = false;
        }
    });
    //TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
    } else imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_avatar);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Выглядит это так. //текст не выводится. по нажатию чекбокса картинки не меняются. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагаю что неправильно реализован адаптер.
Плюс не понимаю когда, как и где вызывать обновление отображения.
Буду рад если подскажете.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39909/discussion-on-question-by-evgeny-goodi----).